# Time Converter - Python Tkinter - General comments on code

Tags: python, tkinter, gui, unit-conversion

I have been learning python since being in lockdown, this is the first Tkinter application I've built without consulting the internet or seeking help anywhere.

It is a time converter where you can select the input unit via a checkbox and the other entry windows will fill with the correct conversion.

I'd like to hear feedback on how it's written, in terms of if I have demonstrated best practice or areas where I could have used less code.

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter.ttk import*

root = Tk() 
Second = IntVar() 
Minute = IntVar() 
Hour = IntVar()

Var1 = IntVar() 
Var2 = IntVar() 
Var3 = IntVar()

def ConvertTime():
    if Var1.get() == 1:
        Minute.set(Second.get()/60)
        Hour.set(Second.get()/3600)
    
    if Var2.get() == 1:
        Second.set(Minute.get()*60)
        Hour.set(Minute.get()*0.01667)

    if Var3.get() == 1:
        Second.set(Hour.get()*3600)
        Minute.set(Hour.get()*60)

class GUI:

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.master = master
        master.title('Time Converter')
        master.geometry('+600+300')

        master.bttn = Button(root, text = 'Convert', command = ConvertTime)
        master.bttn.grid(pady= 5, padx=20, column=1, row=3)

        master.ChooseSecond = Checkbutton(root, text = 'Seconds', variable=Var1, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0)
        master.ChooseSecond.grid(pady=5, padx=20, column=0, row=0)

        master.entry1 = Entry(root, textvariable=Second)
        master.entry1.grid(pady=5, padx=20, column=0, row=1)

        master.ChooseMinute = Checkbutton(root, text = 'Minutes', variable=Var2, onvalue = 1, offvalue=0)
        master.ChooseMinute.grid(pady=5, padx=20, column=1, row=0)

        master.entry2 = Entry(root, textvariable=Minute)
        master.entry2.grid(pady=5, padx=20, column=1, row=1)

        master.ChooseHour = Checkbutton(root, text = 'Hours',variable=Var3, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        master.ChooseHour.grid(pady=5, padx=20, column=2, row=0)

        master.entry3 = Entry(root, textvariable=Hour)
        master.entry3.grid(pady=5, padx=20, column=2, row = 1)

def main():
    GUI(root)
    root.mainloop()

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Avoid putting variables in the global namespace
- Use a more meaningful variable name than `Var1`
- With your current usage, `Varx` variables should be boolean variables, not integer variables, due to them connecting to checkboxes
- Use radio buttons rather than checkboxes, because you really want *exclusive* selection
- No reason not to accept floats instead of ints for your entry boxes
- Generalize a series of conversion factors so that your division and multiplication only need to be expressed once
- No need to set your controls as members on `master`
- [Avoid calling things `master`; it's 2021](https://www.zdnet.com/article/github-to-replace-master-with-main-starting-next-month/)
- Centralize the expression of your padding quantities, since they're all the same
- Separate your business logic from your presentation

### Suggested

```
from enum import Enum
from functools import partial
from tkinter import Button, DoubleVar, Entry, Grid, IntVar, Radiobutton, Tk
from typing import Callable, Dict, Iterable


FACTORS = (1, 60, 60 * 60)


class TimeComponent(Enum):
    SECOND = 0
    MINUTE = 1
    HOUR = 2

    def get_factor(self) -> int:
        return FACTORS[self.value]


class GUIVariable:
    def __init__(
        self,
        root: Tk,
        component: TimeComponent,
        selected_component: IntVar,
    ):
        self.check_button = Radiobutton(
            root,
            text=component.name.title(),
            variable=selected_component,
            value=component.value,
        )

        value = DoubleVar()
        self.get_value: Callable[[], float] = value.get
        self.set_value: Callable[[float], None] = value.set
        self.entry = Entry(root, textvariable=value)


class TimeController:
    def __init__(self, component: TimeComponent, gui: GUIVariable):
        self.get_factor: Callable[[], int] = component.get_factor
        self.gui = gui

    @property
    def normalized(self) -> float:
        return self.gui.get_value() * self.get_factor()

    @normalized.setter
    def normalized(self, x: float) -> None:
        self.gui.set_value(x / self.get_factor())

    def adjust_others(self, others: Iterable['TimeController']):
        value = self.normalized

        for other in others:
            if other is not self:
                other.normalized = value


class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        root = Tk()
        self.run: Callable[[], None] = root.mainloop

        root.title('Time Converter')
        root.geometry('+600+300')

        padded_grid = partial(Grid.grid, pady=5, padx=20)
        convert_button = Button(root, text='Convert', command=self.convert_time)
        padded_grid(convert_button, column=1, row=3)

        self.selected_var = IntVar()
        self.controllers: Dict[TimeComponent, TimeController] = {}
        for component in TimeComponent:
            var = GUIVariable(root, component, self.selected_var)
            padded_grid(var.check_button, column=component.value, row=0)
            padded_grid(var.entry, column=component.value, row=1)

            controller = TimeController(component, var)
            self.controllers[component] = controller

    @property
    def current_controller(self) -> TimeController:
        return self.controllers[
            TimeComponent(self.selected_var.get())
        ]

    def convert_time(self) -> None:
        self.current_controller.adjust_others(self.controllers.values())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    GUI().run()
```

### Alternative

An alternate GUI that is fairly simplified: don't have any selectors or buttons, and when one field changes, update the others.

```
from enum import Enum
from functools import partial
from tkinter import DoubleVar, Entry, Grid, Label, Tk, TclError
from typing import Callable, Dict, Iterable


FACTORS = (1, 60, 60 * 60)


class TimeComponent(Enum):
    SECOND = 0
    MINUTE = 1
    HOUR = 2

    def get_factor(self) -> int:
        return FACTORS[self.value]


class GUIVariable:
    def __init__(
        self,
        root: Tk,
        component: TimeComponent,
        trace: Callable[['GUIVariable'], None],
    ):
        value = DoubleVar()
        value.trace('w', self.trace_inner)
        self.trace = trace
        self.component = component
        self.get_value: Callable[[], float] = value.get
        self.set_value: Callable[[float], None] = value.set

        self.label = Label(root, text=component.name.title())
        self.entry = Entry(root, textvariable=value)

    def trace_inner(self, name: str, _: str, mode: str) -> None:
        self.trace(self)


class TimeController:
    def __init__(self, component: TimeComponent, gui: GUIVariable):
        self.get_factor: Callable[[], int] = component.get_factor
        self.gui = gui

    @property
    def normalized(self) -> float:
        return self.gui.get_value() * self.get_factor()

    @normalized.setter
    def normalized(self, x: float) -> None:
        self.gui.set_value(x / self.get_factor())

    def adjust_others(self, others: Iterable['TimeController']):
        try:
            value = self.normalized
        except TclError:
            return

        for other in others:
            if other is not self:
                other.normalized = value


class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        root = Tk()
        self.run: Callable[[], None] = root.mainloop

        root.title('Time Converter')
        root.geometry('+600+300')

        padded_grid = partial(Grid.grid, pady=5, padx=20)

        self.controllers: Dict[TimeComponent, TimeController] = {}
        for component in TimeComponent:
            var = GUIVariable(root, component, self.on_change)
            padded_grid(var.label, column=component.value, row=0)
            padded_grid(var.entry, column=component.value, row=1)

            controller = TimeController(component, var)
            self.controllers[component] = controller

    def on_change(self, var: GUIVariable) -> None:
        controller = self.controllers[var.component]
        controller.adjust_others(self.controllers.values())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    GUI().run()
```

[image: simplified]

Answer (score 1):

One issue I can see on first glance is the `*`. It's considered bad practice to import everything like that, and here is why from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2386714/13552470) Stack Overflow post:

> - Because it puts a lot of stuff into your namespace (might shadow some other object from previous import and you won't know about it).
> - Because you don't know exactly what is imported and can't easily find from which module a certain thing was imported (readability).
> - Because you can't use cool tools like pyflakes to statically detect errors in your code.

Comment: Overall your feedback is correct - splat-import should generally be discouraged. However, how does this interfere with static analysis? I think it probably doesn't?

Comment: @Reinderien I didn't say anything about the static analsis. The OP asked *"I'd like to hear feedback on how it's written, in terms of if I have demonstrated best practice"*.

Comment: Then what did you mean by _statically detect errors in your code_ ?